# display iPhone-View in a UIPopoverController on iPad (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, position, uipopovercontroller

i'm porting at the moment a iPhone-App to iPad.

I have to redesign some views but some views i want to present in iphone-size as popover.

Popovers are working well, but the content in the view in the popover has a wrong position.

There is a white border around the view an all UI-elements have a wrong position.

**How can I make a correct position?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a missing target-membership of the NIB-Files to show.

I added the nibs to my ipad-Target and it worked.

But there is a new problem: It only work every second build.

Every second build there is the old error.

Have anyone an idea?